# How to run jmeter samplers parallel for multiple requests when one request is dependent on another request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have three requests(req1,req2,req3) which execute based on the CSV config data, the first request will execute 1 time, request 2 will also execute 1 time and request 3 will execute 12 times, so request 2 input is dependent on the request 1 output and request3 input is dependent on request 2 output like that I have to loop for 10 times. so my question is, I want to run the requests with 10 users but when I run like that it's failing due to users are picking the requests randomly and getting lost the data and failing the HTTP requests, Can you please suggest to me which approach will help to run with multiple users parallel with the group of HTTP requests (req1 then req2 then req3) in the same order for 10 times.

I have tried with the Critical section controller which is executing one user at a time and the Parallel controller which is picking the requests randomly
**Ex**: It's picking Req2, Req3, and then Req1.

Below I am attaching my thread group structure, synchronized timer properties, and thread group properties.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1fMn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is going for the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter), it executes all its children in parallel so if you need to invoke `req3` 10 times - put it 10 times under the Parallel Controller.

You can use [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) like:

[image]

Comment: Let me make more clear, I have 3 requests that are to be executed in a sequential manner. As request 2 is dependent on the output of request 1 and request 3 is dependent on the output of request 2. Request 1 and request 2 should be executed once whereas request 3 should execute 10 times.

The above process should be executed for 10 different users simultaneously.

Comment: Then just add 10 users in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and put 3rd request under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller). If you want to execute all the sequence only once and ensure the concurrency - add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer), otherwise just set sufficient number of iterations or test duration in the Thread Group in order to avoid the situation when some threads are done and some are not yet started

Comment: I am using the Loop controller for the 12 requests but in the Loop controller the requests are executing by multiple users parallel and requests are getting failed due to duplicate data( We are reading the data from the CSV Config).


Ex: I have 12 requests with different payload data which I am reading from the CSV config,  when I run the thread group with loop controller having 12 requests then it's hitting req 1, req 3, req4, req 6, req  8, req 2, req 7, req 10, req 12, req 11, req 5, req 9, Here the req 2, req 9 are having the same payload even though it's different in the CSV config